# Angular 4/5 image path in html

Tags: angular, image, path

I have workspace structure that looks like this:

```
src/
   app/
   asset/
       img1.png
       img2.png
       img3.png
```

...
As you can see, app folder and asset folder are on same level. My index file is inside src folder also.
I'm trying to load image inside my component but can't make it show and i get error all the time something like:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/asset/img1.png 404 (Not Found)
```

my html looks like this:

```
<img style="height: 395px; width: 360px;" src="asset/img1.png">
```

Any solution for path?

Comment: Folder name is `asset` or `assets`? Angular by default creates `assets`. Please check

Comment: That is fine ...I have angular assets folder, but I created asset folder for my use

Comment: You will have to add this new folder ("asset") to the "assets" array in the angular json config file. Anyway, is there any good reason to use a different folder, rather than the default defined by angular's team?

Comment: I managed to move "asset" folder under my default angular "image" folder and change path to image/asset/img1.png and now it is working great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the name of folder for assets is `assets`. This is set in `.angular-cli.json` in `apps->assets` settings.

When you put your files there you should be able to link them exactly like you do: `<img style="height: 395px; width: 360px;" src="assets/img1.png">`

Comment: That is fine ...I have angular assets folder by default, but I created asset folder for my use and put images inside

Comment: In that case just add it to configuration I mention in the first paragraph. However I would recommend to use assets folder. That one is for your use :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add your folder in `.angular-cli.json` file like following.

All the custom files that are created out of `src` folder needs to be added here.

```
"apps": [{
    "root": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "assets": [
        "assets",
        "asset" // <-- Like this
    ],
........
}]
```